# Conditional average of columns based on two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes. 1st is a metatable, 2nd is a table with values.

```
df1:
Id  Con Obs
A  one  Day
B  one  Night
C  two  Day
D  two  Night

df2:
Entry  A  B  C  D
val1  2  8  2  8
val2  4  6  4  6
val3  6  4  6  4
val4  8  2  8  2
val5  10 0  10 0
```

I wish to sum df2 based on Condition ('Con') column. For this, I attempted to groupby the Con column and feed that as column to df2 to average.

```
level = df1.groupby(['Con'])['Id'].agg(','.join)
level = level.reset_index()
```

This produces the following:

```
  Con Id
0 one A,B
1 two C,D
```

How do I supply this grouped Id to df2 to get,

```
Output:
Entry AB_sum CD_sum
val1  10  10
val2  10  10
val3  10  10
val4  10  10
val5  10  10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the columns and use groupby on the new column names:

```
(df2.set_index('Entry')
    .rename(columns=df1.set_index('Id')['Con'])
    .groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
)
```

Output:

```
       one  two
Entry          
val1    10   10
val2    10   10
val3    10   10
val4    10   10
val5    10   10
```